# Passing UIImage between ViewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, uiimage

In my first view controller I have a UIImage property which is synthesized in the implementation file. In the second view controller which is pushed, I create a UIImage object there and at the same time set it to the UIImage property from the first view controller. In the end, I dismiss the second view controller. However, it appears that the image was not saved after the viewcontroller was dismissed. My understanding is that since UIImage is a pointer, the data passing was by reference and since the controller was dismissed, so was the UIImage. Is this correct and is there a better way to accomplish this task? For your reference, I am using ARC.

In first view controller (firstVC),

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage *image;
```

In second view controller,

```
[firstVC setImage:self.ivarUIImageView.image];
```

where ivarUIImageVIew is defined as:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *ivarUIImageView;
```

Now lets say in the third view controller, I have in the viewDidLoad method:

```
imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:firstVC.image];
```

where imgView is defined as:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imgView;
```

Comment: In your third VC, how do you define firstVC? If you log firstVC (in viewDidLoad of third VC), is it nil?

Comment: if you just want to deal with the same image, why not putting it in a singleton class (AppDelegate for example) ?

Comment: What you're doing here is really unclear. In second view controller you call setImage on firstVC -- what is firstVC? A pointer to first view controller? An image view? In third view controller, you say you have an IBOutlet imgView, but then you alloc init it -- you don't want to do tht if it's an outlet to an image view in IB.

Comment: @rdelmar Sorry about that. firstVC is in fact a pointer to the first view controller. It turns out the image wasn't displayed because I alloc and init it when it was an outlet to begin with. So there is no need to alloc and init if I have implemented through IB correct? Also, does Obj-C pass UIImage by reference/pointer?

Comment: Yes, you do not want to alloc init an object that you have an outlet to in IB -- that would create a different instance, which is not what you want. And yes, the object is passed by reference.

Comment: So if my property does not have (retain) then the object will be reference nothing correct?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. You should declare the property as strong, which will cause it to be retained. If it's declared as weak, it would be deallocated when its retain count goes to 0. If the image is present in any image views, they would keep a strong reference to it.

Comment: To clarify, let's say the property was declared as weak or nothing at all. When the retain count goes to 0, will all references pointing to that image be NULL and thus empty when displayed to the user?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27803/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-david)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to make sure that the `UIImage` is retained by the first view controller, by making the property `strong`. Also if are displaying it in a `UIImageView` you will have to set the UIImageView's `image` to the new image in order to see change reflected in the UI.

Comment: The UIImage in the first view controller has both the strong, and nonatomic property set. In the second view controller an image is created and I have used the appropriate setter method to set the UIImage. When trying to display the image in a UIImageView, I first alloc and initWithImage with the UIImage property. Nothing is displayed however. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Can you show that code? You want to make sure the UIImageView is added to the view, and that you do the setImage: after the second view re-sets the first image. This can be done by overriding the view controller's setImage: accessor method.

Comment: Does Objective-C pass by reference for UIImage?